# What does testing Hashem mean?

Tags: halacha

I've been reading from some places that it is forbidden to test Hashem. I think the context was when the Jews were in the desert, I think something with Balaam maybe?

What exactly does that mean?

I know there are sources in the Torah but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Something like this? לא תנסו את יהוה אלהיכם Do not test God

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.10/

Comment: See end of chapter 10 in rambam yesodai hatorah http://www.chabad.org/904996/

Answer (score 2):

The context of the phrase you use is usually to have Hashem prove himself to us. Either his existence or that something he previously said is true.

As mentioned in comments above, Ma'aser is an exception - the navi says it enriches and does not causes losses and concludes "[test me by this](http://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.10)".